# Painfully slow MySQL query with indexed columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 4 million rows in total.

When I run the following query, it takes 40 seconds to complete

```
SELECT * FROM `traffic` 
WHERE `callstart_timestamp` >= '2016-09-01 00:00:00' 
AND `callend_timestamp` <= '2016-09-18 00:00:00' 
AND app = 'XXXX'
```

> 416040 total, Query took 40.0631 seconds.

If i remove the condition `AND app = 'XXXX'` from the query, it will finish in less than a second.

Can you please advise what might be causing the problem, since all the columns are indexed?

Query EXPLAIN:

```
SIMPLE; traffic; NULL; ref; app,callend_timestamp,callstart_timestamp; app; 22; const; 1976467; 12.13; Using where;
```

CREATE:

```
CREATE TABLE `traffic` (
  `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_cli` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `ddi` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `callstart_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `callend_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `app` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `lang` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'en'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


ALTER TABLE `traffic`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `app` (`app`),
  ADD KEY `callend_timestamp` (`callend_timestamp`),
  ADD KEY `callstart_timestamp` (`callstart_timestamp`),
  ADD KEY `ddi` (`ddi`);
```

**UPDATE:**

I have implemented some of the answers below and they helped a lot! I will try to figure out which answer better suites my case. I will update with the results.

Comment: just curious, What happens if you disable the use of index on 'app'? i.e it drives off dates rather than 'app'

Comment: Just a suggestion: Move the app to another table and reference with foreign key. Then just filter by the primary key of the app. This comes handy especially if the same app varchar is used on many rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard answer is to create an index on all 3 columns:

```
create index traffic_001 on traffic(app, callstart_timestamp, callend_timestamp)
```

Which follows the general principle of putting exact matching columns before open-ended range matching ones in the index column list.

But there's another idea that I haven't seen done before that might work:

```
SELECT * FROM traffic 
WHERE callstart_timestamp between '2016-09-01 00:00:00' and callend_timestamp
AND callend_timestamp between callstart_timestamp and '2016-09-18 00:00:00' 
AND app = 'XXXX'
```

Logically the start/end values are bounded by each other. Maybe coding this fact into the query will help without adding an index.

Comment: The first index is correct.  The query probably won't use an index.

Comment: @gordon probably not, but the idea seemed cute and I hadn't seen it before (probably because it doesn't work)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 1 index for all 3 columns instead of separate indexes for each one which may confuse the optimizer with the execution plan:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_1
ON traffic(app,callstart_timestamp,callend_timestamp);
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff My bad.